# Form Field Validation in PHP

Tags: php, forms, validation

I am trying to make a php form field validate, and I am hitting a wall. The trouble is, the form field in question generates a NAME for the field ending in brackets like so:
customFieldValue_1[]
When I put in a validation code to make it required, like so:

```
if(empty($post['customFieldValue_1[]']))
    {
    $message    .= '<li>Please enter your Serial Number</li>';
    $valid  = false;
    }
```

It does not work, even if you put something in the field it displays the message and does not save the post. If I leave off the Brackets, it does not validate and saves if the field is empty or not. The brackets are part of the program in the Template page, if I remove them there, the validation works perfectly, but throws a PHP IMPLODE error where the field data should be. I have asked the developer for help, but they don't seem to read English too well and keep giving me the same code that does not work. Anyone seen this before, where brackets kill validation, and how can I get around it?

Comment: why you are using array in value of post :  $post['customFieldValue_1[]'] ??

Comment: Read the question TBI

Comment: Charlie, i think your problems most likely lies in the fact that it's `$_POST[]` and not just `$post[]`

Comment: Hey Mattigins, tried that too, did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP will try and access the post array in a different format e.g:

`$_POST["customFieldValue_1"][0]`

Are you able to add an additional value in the form tag name?

e.g: `<input type="text" name="customFieldValue_1[field]">`

If so you can access it using `$_POST["customFieldValue_1]["field"]` or using the zero index as shown above. Example:

```
<?php
$message = "";
$valid = true;

if ($_POST) {
    if (empty($_POST["customFieldValue_1"][0])) {
        $message .= '<li>Please enter your Serial Number</li>';
        $valid = false;
    }
}

?>

<form name="my_form" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="customFieldValue_1[]">
    <input type="submit" />
</form>

<?php

var_dump($message);
echo "<br />";
var_dump($valid);

?>
```

Comment: I tried that and it doesn't work. It also adds a new forum entry instead of editing the same entry when saving.

Comment: iswinky, I tried it again, using your code above and finally got it to work correctly. It tends to save a whole new forum entry when you edit one, but only if the field starts out empty (which cannot happen anymore) and then you edit the entry and add the data. I will see how it acts in the wild, but you nailed it, thanks!!

Comment: @CharlieTrig No worries!

Answer (score 1):

The [] means it's an input array. The brackets are not a part of the name.

Try checking like this:

```
if(empty($post['customFieldValue_1'][0]))
```

Answer (score -1):

Just use like this

```
if(empty($_POST['customFieldValue_1'])) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Tried that first, and it does not validate - it lets a blank field save.